# Greenplum Database : Currval() not supported

Tags: greenplum

I'm trying to use

```
SELECT currval('myTable_Orderid_seq');
```

I got error: `currval not supported.`

Any work around this is much appreciated.
I need to use currval for each users' session in a multi user environment.

Comment: You can only call `currval()` if you called `nextval()` before that. And please upgrade to a supported version **now**

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name- ty for your comment. I could use nextval w/o an error but i get the same error for CURRVAL. I wish it was on my hand to upgrade to the latest version. That's why i need a work around.

Comment: Again: you must call `currval()` **before** you call `nextval()` ***in the same session***

Comment: When you say "PostgreSQL 8.2.15" am I correct in guessing that you *really* mean "Greenplum Database 4.x" or "Amazon Redshift" or "ParAccel" or something like that, some PostgreSQL fork?

Answer (score 3):

If currval is not available (yet) in the session you can do this:

```
select last_value from myTable_Orderid_seq
```

From the doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

> Although you cannot update a sequence directly, you can use a query
>   like:
>
> SELECT * FROM name;
>
> to examine the parameters and current state of a sequence. In
>   particular, the last_value field of the sequence shows the last value
>   allocated by any session. (Of course, this value might be obsolete by
>   the time it's printed, if other sessions are actively doing nextval
>   calls.)

Comment: Ty for your response. I got the last inserted sequence id, which is fine. But according to your statement 'In particular, the last_value field of the sequence shows the last value allocated by any session.', it seems i may not get the last_value field if ther are multi users entering records. Correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. last_value reflects the last valued issued to any session. So it shows something anyway. It is not necessary that the value was used by the same session, but it shows the last one.

Comment: @Nemo In a less prehistoric PostgreSQL version you'd be doing this with `INSERT ... RETURNING` to get generated values. Not possible in 8.2.x though.

Comment: @Nemo: "it seems i may not get the last_value field if ther are multi users entering records" You'll get the last incremented value of the sequence by any (already terminated) transaction; but I highly doubt  that you really want to do this, this just smells bad (for example, if some transaction rollbacked you'll get a non-recorded sequence value). I told you twice to read carefully the docs and to tell us in detail what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Craig Ringer- Weird! my version of Greenplum db even does not support 'Returning'. Ty for your response.

Comment: @Nemo If you're using Greenplum Database, **say you are using Greenplum Database in the question**, not "postgresql 8.2". It is *not* PostgreSQL, it's a heavily modified fork of PostgreSQL.